# Add right margin to the options menu sub-items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-menu

Currently, my options menu is aligned to the end of the screen. I want to give it a margin, something like `android:layout_marginEnd = "20dp"`. How can I achieve this?

**My options menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_items"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>
            <group android:id="@+id/item1">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/download"
                    android:icon="@drawable/download_icon"
                    android:title="Download"></item>
            </group>

            <group android:id="@+id/item2">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/invite"
                    android:icon="@drawable/invite_icon"
                    android:title="Invite"></item>
            </group>    
        </menu>    
    </item> 
</menu>
```

**My Custom Toolbar:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_below="@id/greetText">     <!--assume it comes somewhere in the centre due to this-->

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**My Theme for menu items:**

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dimGray</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">20dp</item> <!-- doesn't work-->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/quicksand_medium</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/options_menu_background</item>
</style>
```

Here is the image of my problem. It shows how the end of the menu and the screen are aligned. I want space/margin between these two.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the top-right of the screen when you are referring to the end of the screen? Are you using a custom `Toolbar`? If you are using a custom `Toolbar` please post that layout as well.

Comment: My toolbar is somewhere in the middle of the screen, the menu is showing at the end of it. I will post the layout

Comment: The question is still not very clear. Do you want the menu to have some space from the right of the `Toolbar` that you are using or you want to move the `Toolbar` to have the full screen width?

Comment: The options menu which is currently being shown is aligned to the End of the screen. I want to have some space from the rightmost end of the screen, as currently, the rightmost edge of the options menu and the screen overlap.

Comment: I have added the picture, showing how the ends of the menu and the screen are aligned. I want space/margin between these 2

Comment: Thanks. Now the question is clear I think.

Comment: Can you please check my answer and let me know if that works? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you have any update regarding this problem? Let me know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I tried with many things found on the internet, but nothing works. I tried setting the `actionOverflowMenuStyle` with `dropDownHorizontalOffset` attribute which does not work either. Finally, I ended up getting a `PopupMenu` which works just fine. Here is the implementation.

Get your initial menu shorter with a single item which will open up the popup menu as a submenu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_items"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_swipe"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then create another menu, in your `/res/menu/` folder, named `popup_menu.xml` like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_items"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_close_swipe"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Now in your `MainActivity`, just add the following functions to handle the click action of the menu button and the popup menu.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.menu_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_items:
                showPopupMenu();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void showPopupMenu() {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.menu_items));
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
        popup.setGravity(Gravity.END);

        Object menuHelper;
        Class[] argTypes;
        try {
            Field fMenuHelper = PopupMenu.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            fMenuHelper.setAccessible(true);
            menuHelper = fMenuHelper.get(popup);
            argTypes = new Class[]{boolean.class};
            menuHelper.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", argTypes).invoke(menuHelper, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        popup.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.invite:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invite", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.download:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Download", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I put the working code in this [**Github Branch**](https://github.com/masudias/so-playground/tree/SO-Question-57379774). You might consider cloning from that branch and run the application to check if that suffices your expectation.

Hope that helps!